# Javascript - Testing a Character against subset without RegEx

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements

Is there a way to test for occurrence of specific characters in a more elegant way using Javascript syntax but without RegEx? Trying to avoid repetitive 'or' conditions if possible.

```
if (target == "+" || target == "-" || target == "*" || target == "/") {
    alert("hit a function");
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Make it an array and check with `includes`: `if ([ '+', '-', '*', '/' ].includes(target))`

Comment: if (target.includes("+", "-", "*", "/")) ?? may work?

Comment: Weirdly Jamie that tested true for the first character only (+) - ignoring the others. I then swapped the chars, and again it only proved true for the initial entry. Thanks 0stone0.

Comment: Thanks 0stone0, I've added your code, and yes it does indeed work. I would give you an upvote, but I'm so new I don't think I can. Your help however is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways of doing this:

1. Use an array and `includes`: `['+', '-', '*', '/'].includes(target)`
2. Use an object with keys your values and check for that

```
 const values = { '*': true, '-': true, '+': true, '/': true}
 if (values[target] === true)
```

But writing a long boolean condition could also work. Just wrap that in a function so you don't have to c/p code around